# SQL query assistance - query requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL querying requirement that has the following column names. This table has about 400,000 rows.

Handle, first_name, last_name, spouse_id

I need to display all first and last names where spouse_id=handle (for each spouse_id I need to find a match in handle column)

This is part of a bigger SQL query that inner joins 4 other tables. I know that this is simple enough to do. But, don't seem to get if I have to loop through using for each or use a while loop. What do you suggest?

Thanks,

DB

Comment: Never even consider using a loop

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a self join.

```
FROM table1 a
JOin table1 B
   ON a.handle = b.spouse_id
```